# iText not rendering html header tags properly when converting to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, itext

this new problem is tied to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791708/convert-html-with-images-to-pdf-using-itext). Basically I am able to convert an html file that has images and CSS styling to PDF. However, I just noticed that the header tags (h1 - h6) are not rendering properly. I realize that there is an example of this on the iText web page, but the code does not work with what I currently have. Can some help me out with this. Thanks.

```
public class HtmlToPdfConverter {

    public static final String HTML = "C:\\Users\\APPS\\Desktop\\helppages_COPY\\Help_SiteMap.htm";
    public static final String DEST = "C:\\Users\\APPS\\Desktop\\output.pdf";

    //public static final String HTML = "C:\\Users\\APPS\\Desktop\\helppages_COPY\\general\\Training1.htm";
    //public static final String DEST = "C:\\Users\\APPS\\Desktop\\Training1.pdf";

    public static final String IMG_PATH = "C:\\Users\\APPS\\Desktop\\helppages_COPY\\images\\";
    public static final String RELATIVE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\APPS\\Desktop\\helppages_COPY\\images\\";
    public static final String CSS_DIR = "C:\\Users\\APPS\\Desktop\\helppages_COPY\\css\\";

    public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        document.open();

        // CSS
        CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(false);
        FileRetrieve fileRetrieve = new FileRetrieveImpl(CSS_DIR);
        cssResolver.setFileRetrieve(fileRetrieve);

        // HTML
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlPipelineContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlPipelineContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        htmlPipelineContext.setImageProvider(new AbstractImageProvider() {

            @Override
            public String getImageRootPath() {
                return IMG_PATH;
            }
        });

        htmlPipelineContext.setLinkProvider(new LinkProvider() {

            @Override
            public String getLinkRoot() {
                return RELATIVE_PATH;
            }
        });

        // Pipelines
        ElementList elements = new ElementList();
        ElementHandlerPipeline end = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
        //PdfWriterPipeline pdfWriterPipeline = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, pdfWriter);
        //HtmlPipeline hhHtmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlPipelineContext, pdfWriterPipeline);
        HtmlPipeline hhHtmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlPipelineContext, end);
        CssResolverPipeline cssResolverPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, hhHtmlPipeline);

        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker xmlWorker = new XMLWorker(cssResolverPipeline, true);
        XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(xmlWorker);
        xmlParser.parse(new FileInputStream(HTML));

        document.open();
        for (Element e : elements) {
            document.add(e);
        }
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);


        document.close();

        System.out.println("**** Conversion Complete ****");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        new HtmlToPdfConverter().createPdf(DEST);
    }

}
```

Here is an example of one of my html pages. Please not that these pages are just static html pages. They are used with a Java FX based help page application that runs on a user desktop. It allows them to view the pages and then print them to pdf if they choose. The pages are served from a Tomcat server. The pages use an external css style sheet and images. The html file are written in HTML5. Everything in the html file is rendered properly in the pdf file perfectly except for the header tags. For example, in the page I have included the word 'Tutorial' is supposed to a  but as you can see it is not. I have included what my page looks like in the browser and what my pdf looks like so you can see my issue. I hope this is explained well enough. I do not know how to make this any clearer.

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Alert Notification</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/helppages.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="page-padding">

        <table class="header">
            <tr class="header-footer-tr">
                <td class="header-td-left">
                    <a href="#LINKS">Topic References</a>
                </td>
                <td class="header-td-center">
                    <a id="TOP">Create Alert</a>
                </td>
                <td class="header-td-right">
                    <a href="../Help_SiteMap.htm">Topics Map</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p>The Create Alert function provides an Administrator a means to send a &#8220;System&#8221; Alert that immediately displays
            a message window to all users who are currently logged on and to the rest when they do log on until a specified time.
            A system Alert might be used to notify users of changes that effect system access or availability such as scheduled maintenance.
        </p>

        <p>This function is executed as an Admin menu option.</p>

        <div class="image-padding center-content">
            <!-- <img src="../images/Create_Alert.png" alt="Create Alert" /> -->
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="dummy image" />
        </div>

        <p>This window has two text fields, two selection lists, and two buttons.</p>

        <ul>
            <li>Subject - text input to accept a title of the message to all users</li>
            <li>Expire time hour - selection list to specify the hour of the day until which users will see this message at login</li>
            <li>Expire time minute - selection list to specify the minute of the hour until which users will see this message at login
            </li>
            <li>Multi-line text input field to accept message body</li>
            <li>OK - button to accept and broadcast the Alert then close the window</li>
            <li>Close - button to close the window discarding the message</li>
        </ul>

        <br />

        <div class="thin-horizontal-line"></div>

        <h2 id="TUTORIAL">Tutorial</h2>

        <p>
            <b>Send an Alert</b>
        </p>

        <ul>
            <li>Enter an Alert title in the Subject text input field and information for the Alert body (both required fields)</li>
            <li>Optionally, change the expiration time (must be at least 5 minutes in future, 10 is safer)</li>
            <li>Click the OK button</li>
        </ul>

        <br />

        <table class="footer">
            <tr class="header-footer-tr">
                <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center">
                    <a id="LINKS"></a>Local Topics</td>
                <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center">Related Topics</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="verticle-align-top">
                <td class="local-topics-padding">
                    <p>
                        <a href="#TOP">Top of this Page</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#TUTORIAL">Tutorial</a>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-align-right related-topics-padding">
                    <p>
                        <a href="../admin/Admin_Main.htm">Admin Functions</a>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What the page should look like:

[image]

This is what my converted pdf looks like:

[image]

Thank you, and I appreciate all of the help I have been given thus far.

Comment: It would be helpful to add your code, your css and a screenshot of what is printing and what is not...

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? What do you expect from the output? What do you get as output? Why aren't you using the latest version of iText? (See the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml).) The question is unclear. No answer can be given based on the information in the current version of the question.

Comment: I have add more info, as well as code and example to the post. This should the questions as to what my html looks like, what my expected out is, and what is my current out put. As far as why I am not using iText 7. I work for a small business that is working on a small project for the government. The will not pay for the iText 7 license and posting the entire application code to the  public is not an option.